# Debug InfoPath Form

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, infopath

I want to debug a browser enabled InfoPath form with code.

MSDN says [here how](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa944831%28VS.80%29.aspx) to do

But I see that I don't have the option "Open Visual Studio and click Attach to Process on the Tools menu."

Can any one please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Studio is required to debug an InfoPath form with code. If you are missing the menu option, try the keyboard shortcut **Ctrl+Alt+P**.

Right-click on the menu bar and click **Customize** the add the option back. It's **Debug**, **Attach To Process** on the Commands tab.

If Attach To Process is missing then you may be using the copy of Visual Studio that comes with SQL Server. You need to install a "full" version of Visual Studio such as Professional or Team System to get complete debug capabilities.

Comment: Alex, 

I tried following your steps, however I could not get the option to debug.

Comment: Did you check the keyboard shortcut and/or menu option exists by using Customize? If you could click on Attach to Process, did anything happen?

Comment: Alex, I could not find the "Menu" to right click on. Can you please guide me to that Menu.

Comment: I mean any menu, or really I should be saying the "menu bar". If you right-click on that then the Customize button is at the very bottom (from memory).

Comment: Alex, I was able to see the Customize, however I couldn't find the Attach To Process. It is opening is VS2005 not in VS 2008. It was with the installation of SQL Server Management Studio which installed VS 2005 but not entire VS 2005. Is that a problem?

Comment: Yes that will be the problem. SQL Server only installs VS for editing Reporting Services reports, creating Analysis Cubes, etc.. You need to install "full" Visual Studio. I'll update the answer :-)